# Efficiently searching over a list and creating another list with python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a big list and a pandas data frame. For every element in the dataframe, I am searching the list for certain values and returning another list. My dataframe is quite large (>50,000 rows) and list has almost half million items. I have a simplified version below. It takes extremely long time (>5 hours) to run. I was wondering how I can make it more pythonic and efficient. I would really appreciate any suggestions. I am using python 2.7.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
class ODPath(object):    
    def __init__(self,path=[],vol=0):
        self.path = path
        self.vol = vol
    def setpath(self,newpath):
        self.path = newpath
    def setvol(self,newvol):
        self.vol = newvol

def WritePathFile(allpaths_t): 
    for paths_t in allpaths_t:     
        pathvol = paths_t.vol
        path = paths_t.path
        print "Volume is " + str(pathvol)
        for i in range (0,len(path)):
            print """->""" + str(path[i])

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 3),columns=['origin','destination','promise'])
mylist=[[1,2,3,[5,6]],[2,3,1,[1,2,4]],[5,6,1,[4,5,2]],[10,5,1,[1,2,3,4,5]]]
allpaths = []
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    origin = row['origin']
    dest = row['destination']
    promise = row['promise']
    newpathlist=[x for x in mylist if origin<=x[0] if dest<=x[1] if x[2]<=(promise)]

    if not newpathlist: #list is empty
        path=ODPath([],0)
        newpath = [origin] + [dest]
        path.setpath(newpath)   
        path.setvol(dest) 
        allpaths.append(path)
        #do some other assignments
    else:
        for i in newpathlist:            
            path=ODPath([],0)
            newpath=x[3]  #this line is edited.
            path.setpath(newpath)
            path.setvol(promise)                
            allpaths.append(path)

WritePathFile(allpaths)
```

Comment: Have you tried threading or multiprocessing? (Next up, distributed map reduce!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the list you're searching in and create a `pd.Series`.  Then rewrite your search logic using Pandas functions instead of Python loops.

For the result, one idea would be to return an MxN boolean matrix where the rows correspond to the rows of your dataframe and the columns indicate for each item in the list, if it matches.  That's going to help if the number of matched elements is fairly large for each row.  If it's small and variable in number, maybe returning lists is still OK.

Comment: Thanks John. Actually using pd.series is a good idea but one of the mylist element is also a list (please see my edit above). that's why I was wondering creating mylist to pd.series is still a good idea. Any thoughts?

Comment: @G.Deg: Well in your code now you only compare against the single-element values x[0..2].  The multi-element x[3] is only used at the end once the search is done.  So I'd say make a 2D array of the stuff in mylist x[0..2], and then a second 2D array of mylist x[3].

Comment: Sorry I still did not get how I can do it. x[3] can have a list with n elements. How can I store it in a second 2D array? Can you show with an example, if possible?

Comment: @G.Deg: If the list is `[[1,2,3,[5,6]],[2,3,1,[1,2,4]]` then the first 2D array is `[[1,2,3],[2,3,1]]` and the second is `[[5,6],[1,2,4]]`.  Note the width of the second 2D array is not fixed.  Hopefully the max `len(x[3])` is not too large.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually, I did not implement but I got inspired from what you said. I load mylist to a new dataframe and merged the two dataframes. I did not know that a dataframe can have list elements. It is now pretty fast. Great idea. Thanks.